# JavaScript, встроенный при помощи XSLT

Tags: xml, javascript, xslt

Объясните, пожалуйста, причину, по которой на [странице](http://prozaik.16mb.com/question/alert/index.xml) при клике по блоку .content в последней версии Opera не срабатывает JavaScript, а в последней версии FF срабатывает.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="xsl/rules2.xsl" ?>
<authors>
    <title_head>мы поэты</title_head>
    <author id="1">
        <fio>
            <f>Пушкин</f>
            <i>Александр</i>
            <o>Сергеевич</o>
        </fio>
        <born>1799</born>
    </author>
    <author id="2">
        <fio>
            <f>Лермонтов</f>
            <i>Михаил</i>
            <o>Юрьевич</o>
        </fio>
        <born>1814</born>
    </author>
</authors>
```

Comment: скрипт это `alert(666)`? хотя там больше скриптов нету, но всё же,  в последней версии оперы, т.е. 12, всё работает. я бы больше беспокоился на счёт вырвиглазного сочетания цветов

Comment: версия 12.01 . не работает... но всё равно спасибо

Comment: Opera 9.63 работает, ie 8 работает

Answer (score 1):

Оберните содержимое скрипта в CDATA.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".content").click(function(){
            alert(666);
        });

    });
// ]]>
</script>
```